# Inductance of toroidal-cylindrical inductor?

Tags: inductor, inductance, theory, physics, passive-components

If the inductance of a solenoid is \$L_{\text{sol}}=\frac{\mu N^2 A}{l}\$ and the inductance of a toroid is \$L_{\text{tor}}=\frac{\mu N^2 r^2}{D}\$, is it correct to assume that the inductance of a "toroidal-cylindrical" inductor is simply  equal to several toroidal inductors connected in series, \$L_{\text{tor-sol}}=N_1\frac{\mu N_2^2 r^2}{D}\$, or the contribution of the "solenoidal effect" is significant? What would be the total inductance then? Does this type of geometry has any practical use?

[image: toroidal-cylindrical inductor]

Answer (score 1):

> Does this type of geometry has any practical use?

Not that I'm aware of and, TBH I don't think it ever will. The significant mistake you have made is in assuming that a long solenoid wrapped around a "big" core will be significantly "different" to a single wire wrapped around the same "big" core. It won't because you have opposing currents in the smaller loops of the solenoid cancelling out as the solenoid snakes around the "big" core. Those cancellations do not contribute to a significant increase in flux in the "big" core.

The opposing currents won't do anything magnetically useful (that I can see) and the extra resistance (due to the smaller loop of the solenoid) just wastes power.

Sorry to be so negative but it looks like a waste of time BUT who knows, in the future something may be required that needs this. I can't say that - all I can do is analyse the efficasy of the idea in terms of magnetic and resistive properties.

Answer (score 0):

1. Area od solenoid magnetic core =A wherea area of toroid =pi*r^2 (r=radius of toroid core)
2. length of solenoid = L whereas toroid magnetic length=pi*D
3. substitute toroidal magnetic circuit value in solenoid inductance equaton.
   vtingole

Answer (score 0):

While the inductance of a solenoid is, indeed,

$$L_{\text{sol}}=\frac{\mu N^2 A}{l}$$

you've left out the area term in the toroid's equation, which should read:

$$L_{\text{tor}}=\frac{\mu N^2 A}{2\pi r}$$

with "A" being the cross-sectional area of the solenoid's core and \$ 2\pi r\$ being the length (circumference) of the core, so both equations are really the same thing, I think.

As for the the utility as an inductor, with your proposed winding the magnetic lines of force are running orthogonally to the axis of the core, and I can't quit wrap my head around what that would do to the inductance.

As a transformer though, with the big conductor as one of the windings, just about every power transformer in the world is wound like that.

Comment: A and r cancel out to give r/D